# How do I access Intent information after the application is closed?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service

So I have an android app that creates a service that will run in the background for the user even when the application is closed.

I have them enter a number that is sent with the Intent but once the user closes the application the Intent is no longer accessible. How can I make the information stored in the intent still accessible even if they close the app?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if the application is closed then the Service will try and restart based on the integer returned in the onStartCommand method. If *START_REDELIVER_INTENT* is used the Service will restart with the original Intent.